# Can't Find Custom Login Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I fully admit that I am a SharePoint newbie so this question may seem a bit weak.

I inherited a SharePoint site and I want to make some changes to the FBA Login page but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where it is so that I can change it. I have looked in the configuration for the site in Central Admin and it says it is using a page named autosignin.aspx
[image: Capture From Central Admin]

So I went looking and found this file:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN\autosignin.aspx

But this file has virtually no markup in it at all (as seen here)

---

```
<%@ Assembly Name="OrbitOne.SharePoint.Claims.SignIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3c7a593397c60142" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="OrbitOne.SharePoint.Claims.SignIn.AutoSignin"  %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

while the page, when displayed, has a large image and footer logo and text along with the text boxes for User Name and password.

**What am I missing?**

Using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Doug

Comment: How is URL to login page (in browser) look like?

Comment: Here it is: https://[MY SITE'S URL]/_forms/default.aspx  I looked at this page as well and it also has relatively no html in it. Looks basically the same as the autosignin.aspx page HTML listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I had a sneaking suspicion that they may have done something outside of SharePoint on this and that seems to have been the case. I found the page that they are using for the custom login.

Thanks to all who may have given this any thought and put any work into it.